# detecting if an object is present using a sensor of some sort

Tags: sensor

Yesterday I when I came home I found my soldering iron was still switched on from few hours before. I have one of those big aluminium holders you get with expensive soldering stations. I was wondering if it's possible to mount a sensor where the red blob is in the picture.

[image]

Pseudo code

```
if object is there then 
    //start timer
else
   //stop and reset timer
end if 

if 1 minute has pass
 //switch off 
endif
```

Is that easy to do? I would need help selecting a solid state relay too and never wired one up.  Preferably isolates line and neutral conductors like a British socket does.

Comment: A somewhat [related question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35116/how-to-add-temperature-control-to-a-soldering-iron/) about adding temperature control to an iron. You could modify the firmware to turn off the iron after a certain time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would mount a microswitch like this one

[image]

under the iron, so that it rests on the long lever. There are microswitches in all kinds of flavors, but the long lever has the advantage that it doesn't need much force (read: weight) to activate.

Comment: ah ok that's much simplier. Haha I always over engineer things.

Comment: @Ageis - Like my dear friend [Albert](http://www.alberteinsteinsite.com/quotes/einsteinquotes.html) says: *"Everything should be as simple as possible, but not simpler."* :-)

Comment: @stevenvh:- Nice quote !!, but I had a question, how these microswitches fulfill the timer logic?

Comment: @peril - They don't. Ageis asked for a sensor, and that's what the microswitch is. If he needs an answer for the timer as well he'll have to update his question. :-)

Comment: @stevenvh:- Oh I see his pseudo code and actual question are ambiguous. :)

Comment: @peril - yeah, that is a bit ambiguous indeed. I just followed the title (*"detecting if an object is present using a sensor of some sort"*) and the question in the text (*"I was wondering if it's possible to mount a sensor"*).

Comment: ah right sorry this time I gave too much information. I usually give too little then ppl don't know what am trying to do lol.

Answer (score 1):

Steven's answer is the simplest solution you can get, but just for the record you could also use a PTC or NTC resistor mounted near where the tip of the iron would be. That would make the detector "invisible" and it's also a cheap solution.